# Use animateinline inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, animations, animate

I am doing a `beamer` presentation with animated `tikzpicture` environments. In the MWE, the top figure consists of a plot which never changes and a point moving on it. Since the plot is long to compile, I saved it in a file `image.pdf` which I load in a `node`. Unfortunately, I did not find a way of loading the image once for all: my current solution is to load it at every step (i.e. about 600 times...).

The bottom plot consists of a curve drawn by `\pgfplots` from a data file `data.dat`. I have 5 different data files (I use the same one in the MWE) which are loaded one after the other using `only`. For one data file, I am plotting an animated point on the curve. Again, I did not found another solution that plotting the curve at every iteration (i.e. about 600 times...).

In total, the compilation takes several minutes. I reduced the number of iterations so that the provided code should take about 20 seconds.

So, there are my questions:

1. How can I load the image once for all in the top plot?
2. How can I plot each of the five curves once for all in the bottom plot?
3. Are there clumsinesses in the code which I would not have spotted?

I tried to move the `animateinline` and `multiframe` within in `tikzpicture`, causing the error:

> File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{animate}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
1.733   1.770   1.807   1.843   1.880   1.918
}\mytable

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    % Data to read [a single file "data.dat" is used here for simplification purposes] 
    \only<1>{\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable\def\indice{5}}
    \only<2>{\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable\def\indice{4}}
    \only<3>{\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable\def\indice{3}}
    \only<4>{\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable\def\indice{2}}
    \only<5>{\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable\def\indice{1}}
    % Get number of rows
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{int(\pgfplotsretval-1)}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{animateinline}[loop,poster=first]{10}
            \multiframe{201}{i=0+1}{%
                % Get last value of first column of data.dat 
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\rows}{[index]0}\of\datatable%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
                % Get x-coordinate of moving point
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\mytable%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\tfirst}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    % top plot
                    \begin{axis}[%
                        scale only axis,
                        axis on top,
                        width=4cm, height=2.25cm,
                        xmin=1.5, xmax=2.2,
                        ymin=0.3, ymax=1.5,
                        ]

                        % LOADS IMAGE AT EVERY STEP!
                        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:1.5,0.3) {\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=2.25cm]{./image}}; 
                        \addplot[mark=*,red] coordinates {(\tfirst,\tmax-\tfirst)};
                    \end{axis}

                    % bottom plot
                    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-4.3)}]
                        \begin{axis}[every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},
                            scale only axis,
                            width=5.025cm,height=3.15cm,  
                            enlarge x limits={value=0.02,upper},
                            enlarge y limits=false,
                            xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}
                        ]
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]0}\of{\datatable}\let\time\pgfplotsretval
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]\indice}\of{\datatable}\let\position\pgfplotsretval
                        \addplot[mark=*,blue] coordinates {(\time,\position)};

                         % PLOTS HOLE CURVE AT EVERY STEP!!
                        \addplot [thick,blue] table [x index=0, y index=\indice] {\datatable};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{scope}
          \end{tikzpicture}%
        }
        \end{animateinline}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Link to `data.dat`: [hosted on filedropper](http://www.filedropper.com/data_12)

Link to `image.pdf`: [hosted on filedropper](http://www.filedropper.com/image_2) or to [Original on Overleaf](https://writelatex.s3.amazonaws.com/filepicker/OxGKpxuLTiGTijkKz5c6_frog.jpg)

Link to the complete project (can be downloaded as zip): [hosted on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/4431751fhgfhg#/13248276/)

Comment: I took the liberty to change the code in order to make use of all rows and columns (for the five different beamer slides) of the input data, and to get the same output as in the answer. For comparison purposes. Feel free to undo.

Comment: @AlexG No worries. Thank you for your answer which I'll read thoroughly a bit later (could take a few weeks, but I'll read it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static part of the whole `tikzpicture`, i. e. the top image with axes and the bottom plotted curve plus axes & axis labels can be saved into a PDF XObject using the **`xsavebox`** package.

The `tikzpicture` thus saved can be inserted as a background image while plotting on its top the ***isolated*** red and moving blue dots to create the animation frames.

Unlike inserting standard saveboxes, referencing PDF-XObject-based saveboxes does not replicate the saved code inside the PDF output file.

A few additions were necessary to the original code of the question:

The `axis` option

```
scale only axis
```

for the background and when plotting the isolated dots, and

```
hide axis
```

when plotting the isolated dots.

The axis ranges must be determined from the input data, because they must be set as axis options when plotting the single dots.

Furthermore, the bounding box lower left coordinate of the background plot needs to be saved into TeX macros for correct placement of the background node in the animation frames.

Compilation times and PDF file sizes with the original data sets (5 x 201 data points) and the original [-->`image.jpg`<--](https://writelatex.s3.amazonaws.com/filepicker/OxGKpxuLTiGTijkKz5c6_frog.jpg)

- original LaTeX source: 2:17 min ; 4,235,154 B
- LaTeX code below: 0:37 min ; 1,083,389 B

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{animate}

%saveboxes without code replication, based on PDF XObjects
\usepackage{xsavebox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% command for saving node anchor coords into  TeX macros
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\saveCoordsOfNodeAnchor[4]{{%
  % #1: macro taking x coordinate
  % #2: macro taking y coordinate
  % #3: <Node id>
  % #4: <anchor>
  \pgfpointanchor{#3}{#4}%
  \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgf@xx}%
  \xdef#1{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfmathparse{\pgf@y/\pgf@yy}%
  \xdef#2{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the data file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
0 0.7556 -0.4146 -1.729 -0.8786 1.
0.01406 0.6943 -0.4725 -1.721 -0.8583 0.9466
0.02812 0.6239 -0.5308 -1.702 -0.8333 0.8843
0.04218 0.5448 -0.5892 -1.673 -0.8041 0.8136
0.05624 0.4573 -0.6474 -1.635 -0.7713 0.7348
0.0703 0.3621 -0.705 -1.588 -0.7352 0.6486
0.08436 0.2598 -0.7617 -1.532 -0.6966 0.5555
0.09842 0.1513 -0.8171 -1.468 -0.6558 0.4563
0.1125 0.03716 -0.871 -1.397 -0.6136 0.3516
0.1265 -0.08161 -0.923 -1.319 -0.5705 0.2421
0.1406 -0.2041 -0.9727 -1.236 -0.5271 0.1286
0.1547 -0.3294 -1.02 -1.148 -0.4839 0.01185
0.1687 -0.4565 -1.065 -1.056 -0.4416 -0.1073
0.1828 -0.5844 -1.106 -0.9608 -0.4007 -0.2282
0.1968 -0.7119 -1.144 -0.8638 -0.3616 -0.3499
0.2109 -0.838 -1.179 -0.7657 -0.325 -0.4717
0.225 -0.9617 -1.21 -0.6674 -0.2913 -0.5927
0.239 -1.082 -1.237 -0.57 -0.2609 -0.7122
0.2531 -1.197 -1.26 -0.4743 -0.2343 -0.8296
0.2672 -1.307 -1.278 -0.3814 -0.2118 -0.9439
0.2812 -1.411 -1.293 -0.292 -0.1938 -1.055
0.2953 -1.507 -1.303 -0.2071 -0.1805 -1.161
0.3093 -1.594 -1.309 -0.1275 -0.1721 -1.263
0.3234 -1.672 -1.31 -0.0539 -0.169 -1.359
0.3375 -1.74 -1.307 0.0129 -0.1711 -1.45
0.3515 -1.797 -1.299 0.07228 -0.1787 -1.534
0.3656 -1.843 -1.288 0.1236 -0.1917 -1.611
0.3796 -1.878 -1.271 0.1665 -0.2102 -1.681
0.3937 -1.899 -1.251 0.2004 -0.234 -1.745
0.4078 -1.909 -1.227 0.2249 -0.2632 -1.8
0.4218 -1.905 -1.199 0.2399 -0.2976 -1.848
0.4359 -1.889 -1.168 0.2451 -0.3369 -1.889
0.4499 -1.859 -1.133 0.2405 -0.3811 -1.921
0.464 -1.817 -1.095 0.226 -0.4298 -1.947
0.4781 -1.763 -1.053 0.2017 -0.4827 -1.964
0.4921 -1.696 -1.01 0.1679 -0.5396 -1.975
0.5062 -1.617 -0.9633 0.1248 -0.6001 -1.978
0.5202 -1.527 -0.9149 0.0727 -0.6638 -1.974
0.5343 -1.427 -0.8647 0.01209 -0.7303 -1.964
0.5484 -1.317 -0.8129 -0.05651 -0.7993 -1.948
0.5624 -1.198 -0.7598 -0.1325 -0.8703 -1.926
0.5765 -1.07 -0.7058 -0.2153 -0.9428 -1.899
0.5905 -0.936 -0.6512 -0.304 -1.017 -1.868
0.6046 -0.7956 -0.5963 -0.398 -1.091 -1.832
0.6187 -0.6503 -0.5414 -0.4964 -1.165 -1.792
0.6327 -0.5012 -0.4868 -0.5983 -1.24 -1.749
0.6468 -0.3496 -0.4328 -0.7029 -1.314 -1.704
0.6608 -0.1967 -0.3798 -0.8091 -1.386 -1.657
0.6749 -0.04371 -0.3279 -0.9161 -1.457 -1.608
0.689 0.1081 -0.2776 -1.023 -1.527 -1.559
0.703 0.2574 -0.2291 -1.128 -1.593 -1.51
0.7171 0.4031 -0.1825 -1.232 -1.658 -1.461
0.7312 0.5439 -0.1383 -1.332 -1.719 -1.413
0.7452 0.6787 -0.0966 -1.428 -1.776 -1.366
0.7593 0.8062 -0.05764 -1.52 -1.83 -1.322
0.7733 0.9255 -0.02164 -1.606 -1.88 -1.28
0.7874 1.036 0.01121 -1.685 -1.926 -1.241
0.8015 1.135 0.04075 -1.757 -1.967 -1.205
0.8155 1.224 0.06681 -1.821 -2.003 -1.173
0.8296 1.301 0.08926 -1.877 -2.034 -1.146
0.8436 1.366 0.108 -1.924 -2.06 -1.122
0.8577 1.418 0.1229 -1.962 -2.081 -1.103
0.8718 1.456 0.1339 -1.989 -2.096 -1.089
0.8858 1.481 0.1409 -2.007 -2.106 -1.081
0.8999 1.492 0.144 -2.015 -2.11 -1.077
0.9139 1.488 0.143 -2.013 -2.109 -1.078
0.928 1.471 0.1381 -2. -2.102 -1.084
0.9421 1.44 0.1291 -1.977 -2.089 -1.095
0.9561 1.395 0.1163 -1.945 -2.072 -1.112
0.9702 1.337 0.09953 -1.903 -2.048 -1.133
0.9842 1.266 0.07902 -1.852 -2.02 -1.158
0.9983 1.183 0.05483 -1.792 -1.986 -1.188
1.012 1.089 0.02709 -1.724 -1.948 -1.222
1.026 0.9843 -0.004049 -1.648 -1.905 -1.259
1.04 0.8697 -0.03843 -1.565 -1.857 -1.299
1.055 0.7464 -0.07586 -1.477 -1.805 -1.343
1.069 0.6152 -0.1162 -1.383 -1.749 -1.388
1.083 0.4775 -0.1591 -1.285 -1.69 -1.435
1.097 0.3342 -0.2044 -1.183 -1.627 -1.484
1.111 0.1866 -0.252 -1.078 -1.562 -1.533
1.125 0.03594 -0.3014 -0.972 -1.494 -1.583
1.139 -0.1166 -0.3525 -0.865 -1.424 -1.632
1.153 -0.2697 -0.4049 -0.7583 -1.352 -1.68
1.167 -0.4221 -0.4585 -0.6528 -1.279 -1.726
1.181 -0.5727 -0.5128 -0.5494 -1.204 -1.77
1.195 -0.7201 -0.5676 -0.449 -1.13 -1.811
1.209 -0.8632 -0.6225 -0.3526 -1.055 -1.849
1.223 -1.001 -0.6773 -0.261 -0.9813 -1.883
1.237 -1.132 -0.7317 -0.175 -0.9081 -1.913
1.251 -1.256 -0.7853 -0.09539 -0.8362 -1.937
1.265 -1.371 -0.8378 -0.02284 -0.7662 -1.957
1.28 -1.476 -0.8889 0.04202 -0.6983 -1.97
1.294 -1.572 -0.9383 0.09862 -0.6331 -1.977
1.308 -1.656 -0.9857 0.1465 -0.5708 -1.977
1.322 -1.729 -1.031 0.1852 -0.512 -1.971
1.336 -1.79 -1.073 0.2145 -0.457 -1.957
1.35 -1.839 -1.113 0.2341 -0.406 -1.936
1.364 -1.875 -1.15 0.2439 -0.3595 -1.907
1.378 -1.898 -1.183 0.2439 -0.3176 -1.87
1.392 -1.908 -1.213 0.234 -0.2806 -1.826
1.406 -1.906 -1.239 0.2144 -0.2486 -1.775
1.42 -1.89 -1.261 0.1854 -0.222 -1.715
1.434 -1.863 -1.28 0.1472 -0.2007 -1.649
1.448 -1.823 -1.294 0.1002 -0.1848 -1.575
1.462 -1.771 -1.303 0.04494 -0.1744 -1.494
1.476 -1.709 -1.309 -0.01806 -0.1694 -1.407
1.49 -1.636 -1.31 -0.08818 -0.1698 -1.314
1.504 -1.553 -1.307 -0.1647 -0.1755 -1.215
1.519 -1.462 -1.299 -0.247 -0.1862 -1.111
1.533 -1.362 -1.287 -0.3341 -0.2018 -1.002
1.547 -1.256 -1.27 -0.4253 -0.222 -0.8898
1.561 -1.143 -1.249 -0.5197 -0.2465 -0.7739
1.575 -1.025 -1.224 -0.6163 -0.275 -0.6555
1.589 -0.9031 -1.195 -0.7142 -0.307 -0.5351
1.603 -0.7781 -1.163 -0.8125 -0.3421 -0.4136
1.617 -0.6512 -1.126 -0.9102 -0.38 -0.2918
1.631 -0.5234 -1.087 -1.006 -0.42 -0.1704
1.645 -0.3958 -1.044 -1.1 -0.4617 -0.05026
1.659 -0.2694 -0.9978 -1.19 -0.5045 0.06786
1.673 -0.1453 -0.9493 -1.276 -0.5478 0.1832
1.687 -0.02446 -0.8984 -1.357 -0.5912 0.2948
1.701 0.0922 -0.8455 -1.431 -0.6339 0.4022
1.715 0.2038 -0.7909 -1.499 -0.6755 0.5043
1.729 0.3094 -0.7348 -1.559 -0.7153 0.6007
1.744 0.4084 -0.6776 -1.611 -0.7528 0.6906
1.758 0.5 -0.6197 -1.655 -0.7874 0.7733
1.772 0.5836 -0.5614 -1.688 -0.8185 0.8483
1.786 0.6586 -0.503 -1.712 -0.8458 0.9151
1.8 0.7247 -0.4448 -1.726 -0.8686 0.9732
1.814 0.7814 -0.3872 -1.729 -0.8865 0.9757
1.828 0.8285 -0.3304 -1.721 -0.8994 0.9179
1.842 0.8658 -0.2748 -1.702 -0.9075 0.8512
1.856 0.8931 -0.2205 -1.673 -0.9107 0.7757
1.87 0.9106 -0.168 -1.632 -0.9094 0.692
1.884 0.9182 -0.1174 -1.581 -0.9037 0.6003
1.898 0.9162 -0.06883 -1.519 -0.894 0.5012
1.912 0.9047 -0.0226 -1.447 -0.8805 0.3952
1.926 0.8843 0.02118 -1.365 -0.8634 0.2829
1.94 0.8552 0.06238 -1.273 -0.8432 0.165
1.954 0.818 0.1009 -1.173 -0.8201 0.04202
1.968 0.7731 0.1367 -1.065 -0.7945 -0.08518
1.983 0.7214 0.1696 -0.9498 -0.7667 -0.2159
1.997 0.6633 0.1998 -0.828 -0.7371 -0.3493
2.011 0.5997 0.2272 -0.7007 -0.7061 -0.4846
2.025 0.5312 0.2518 -0.5688 -0.6739 -0.6211
2.039 0.4588 0.2738 -0.4334 -0.6409 -0.7577
2.053 0.3832 0.2932 -0.2955 -0.6075 -0.8938
2.067 0.3052 0.3101 -0.1563 -0.574 -1.029
2.081 0.2258 0.3247 -0.01679 -0.5406 -1.161
2.095 0.1457 0.3371 0.1218 -0.5077 -1.29
2.109 0.06586 0.3475 0.2583 -0.4756 -1.416
2.123 -0.01292 0.3561 0.3917 -0.4445 -1.537
2.137 -0.08981 0.363 0.5207 -0.4146 -1.652
2.151 -0.164 0.3685 0.6444 -0.3863 -1.762
2.165 -0.2348 0.3727 0.7616 -0.3596 -1.864
2.179 -0.3014 0.3758 0.8713 -0.3349 -1.959
2.193 -0.3632 0.3781 0.9726 -0.3122 -2.046
2.208 -0.4195 0.3796 1.065 -0.2917 -2.125
2.222 -0.4698 0.3805 1.147 -0.2736 -2.194
2.236 -0.5136 0.381 1.218 -0.258 -2.254
2.25 -0.5505 0.3812 1.278 -0.2449 -2.305
2.264 -0.58 0.3813 1.325 -0.2345 -2.345
2.278 -0.6019 0.3812 1.361 -0.2268 -2.374
2.292 -0.616 0.3812 1.384 -0.2219 -2.393
2.306 -0.6221 0.3812 1.393 -0.2197 -2.401
2.32 -0.6202 0.3812 1.39 -0.2204 -2.399
2.334 -0.6102 0.3812 1.374 -0.2239 -2.385
2.348 -0.5924 0.3813 1.345 -0.2301 -2.361
2.362 -0.5668 0.3813 1.304 -0.2391 -2.327
2.376 -0.5338 0.3812 1.251 -0.2508 -2.282
2.39 -0.4936 0.3808 1.185 -0.2651 -2.227
2.404 -0.4466 0.3801 1.109 -0.2819 -2.162
2.418 -0.3934 0.3789 1.022 -0.3012 -2.089
2.432 -0.3344 0.3771 0.9254 -0.3228 -2.006
2.447 -0.2702 0.3745 0.82 -0.3464 -1.915
2.461 -0.2015 0.3709 0.7066 -0.3721 -1.816
2.475 -0.129 0.3661 0.5862 -0.3996 -1.71
2.489 -0.05344 0.3599 0.4598 -0.4287 -1.598
2.503 0.02445 0.3522 0.3286 -0.4592 -1.48
2.517 0.1038 0.3428 0.1936 -0.4908 -1.357
2.531 0.1839 0.3315 0.0559 -0.5233 -1.229
2.545 0.2638 0.318 -0.08325 -0.5565 -1.098
2.559 0.3426 0.3023 -0.2228 -0.5899 -0.9646
2.573 0.4196 0.2843 -0.3615 -0.6235 -0.8291
2.587 0.4938 0.2636 -0.4983 -0.6567 -0.6926
2.601 0.5644 0.2404 -0.6322 -0.6893 -0.5559
2.615 0.6306 0.2145 -0.762 -0.721 -0.4199
2.629 0.6917 0.1858 -0.8868 -0.7514 -0.2854
2.643 0.7469 0.1543 -1.006 -0.7802 -0.1532
2.657 0.7954 0.12 -1.118 -0.807 -0.02405
2.672 0.8367 0.08287 -1.222 -0.8314 0.1012
2.686 0.8701 0.04307 -1.318 -0.8532 0.2219
2.7 0.8951 0.0006246 -1.405 -0.872 0.3372
2.714 0.9113 -0.04434 -1.482 -0.8874 0.4466
2.728 0.9183 -0.09169 -1.55 -0.8991 0.5493
2.742 0.9158 -0.1412 -1.607 -0.907 0.645
2.756 0.9035 -0.1928 -1.653 -0.9106 0.7329
2.77 0.8813 -0.2462 -1.688 -0.9097 0.8128
2.784 0.8492 -0.3011 -1.713 -0.9042 0.8841
2.798 0.8073 -0.3573 -1.726 -0.8939 0.9466
2.812 0.7556 -0.4146 -1.729 -0.8786 1.
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
1.733   1.770   1.807   1.843   1.880   1.918
}\mytable

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% command for saving static plot content (the top image and the bottom curve
% with axes and labels) into xsavebox
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\saveStaticPlot{%
  \xsbox{staticPlotContent}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % top plot
      \begin{axis}[%
        scale only axis,
        axis on top,
        width=4cm,
        height=2.25cm,
        xmin=1.5, xmax=2.2,
        ymin=0.3, ymax=1.5,
      ]
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:1.5,0.3) {%
          %resize image to fit within the axis box
          \resizebox{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}}{\thefrog}
        };
      \end{axis}
      % bottom plot
      \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-4.3)}]
        \begin{axis}[every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},
          scale only axis,
          width=5.025cm,height=3.15cm,  
          xmin=\xMin, xmax=\xMax,
          ymin=\yMin, ymax=\yMax,
          enlarge x limits={value=0.02,upper},
          xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}
        ]
        \addplot [thick,blue] table [x index=0, y index=\indice] {\datatable};
        \end{axis}
      \end{scope}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      %save BBox coordinates
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \saveCoordsOfNodeAnchor{\llx}{\lly}{current bounding box}{south west}
      %\saveCoordsOfNodeAnchor{\urx}{\ury}{current bounding box}{north east}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% save bitmap image once for all
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\xsbox{frog}{\includegraphics{./image}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    % Data to read [a single file "data.dat" is used here for simplification purposes] 
    \only<1>{%
      \pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable%
      \def\indice{5}%
      %get min and max values
      %time
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      %data
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
    }
    \only<2>{%
      \pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable%
      \def\indice{4}%
      %get min and max values
      %time
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      %data
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
    }
    \only<3>{%
      \pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable%
      \def\indice{3}%
      %get min and max values
      %time
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      %data
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
    }
    \only<4>{%
      \pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable%
      \def\indice{2}%
      %get min and max values
      %time
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      %data
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
    }
    \only<5>{%
      \pgfplotstableread[col sep=space,row sep=newline,header=true]{./data.dat}\datatable%
      \def\indice{1}%
      %get min and max values
      %time
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]0},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      %data
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMin}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={[index]\indice},sort cmp={float >}]\tmptble\datatable%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\tmptble%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
    }
    % Get number of rows
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{int(\pgfplotsretval-1)}

    \begin{center}
      \saveStaticPlot%  save the satic plot with the current data
      \begin{animateinline}[loop,poster=first]{10}
        \multiframe{201}{i=0+1}{%
          % Get last value of first column of data.dat 
          \pgfplotstablegetelem{\rows}{[index]0}\of\datatable%
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmax}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
          % Get x-coordinate of moving point
          \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]\indice}\of\mytable%
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\tfirst}{\pgfplotsretval}% 
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            % insert static plot as a node at (\llx,\lly)
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] at (\llx,\lly) {\thestaticPlotContent};
            %\useasboundingbox (\llx,\lly) rectangle (\urx,\ury);

            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            % overlay the red and blue dots
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            % top plot (red point only!!!)
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \begin{axis}[%
              scale only axis,
              % note: axes hidden, no axis labels
              hide axis,
              width=4cm, height=2.25cm,
              xmin=1.5, xmax=2.2,
              ymin=0.3, ymax=1.5,
            ]
              \addplot[mark=*,red] coordinates {(\tfirst,\tmax-\tfirst)};
            \end{axis}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            % bottom plot, blue point only, axes hidden, no axis labels
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-4.3)}]
              \begin{axis}[every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},
                  scale only axis,
                  hide axis,
                  xmin=\xMin, xmax=\xMax,
                  enlarge x limits={value=0.02,upper},
                  ymin=\yMin, ymax=\yMax,
                  width=5.025cm,height=3.15cm,  
              ]
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]0}\of{\datatable}\let\time\pgfplotsretval
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]\indice}\of{\datatable}\let\position\pgfplotsretval
                \addplot[mark=*,blue] coordinates {(\time,\position)};
              \end{axis}
            \end{scope}
          \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
      \end{animateinline}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

To see the isolated dots, enable

```
\saveCoordsOfNodeAnchor{\urx}{\ury}{current bounding box}{north east}
```

and change

```
\node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] at (\llx,\lly){\thestaticPlotContent};
%\useasboundingbox (\llx,\lly) rectangle (\urx,\ury);
```

to

```
%\node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] at (\llx,\lly){\thestaticPlotContent};
\useasboundingbox (\llx,\lly) rectangle (\urx,\ury);
```

Comment: Will I benefit from PDF XObjects if I use `includegraphics` of PDF XObjects? For example if I generate one file with 100 pages, using the same background image as an XObject. Then, I import the PDFs using `animateinline`. Will the backgrounds be understood as XObjects?

Comment: Yes, you can be assured this to happen. PdftTeX will never replace an existing XObject with inline code upon embedding.